# How to compare two arrays in Standard SQL (BigQuery)?

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery, nested

I have two tables with the exact same schema, one of the fields is a record and I try to compare this field between the two tables.

For example:

Table A:

```
{ Name: 'Mary',
  DOB: '06.06.1970',
  Children:[
            { Name: John,   Age: 6 },
            { Name: Agatha, Age: 10}
           ]
},
{ Name: 'Bob',
  DOB: '30.03.1982',
  Children:[
            { Name: Anthony, Age: 9 },
            { Name: William, Age: 4 },
            { Name: Rose,    Age: 2 }
           ]
},
{ Name: 'Adam',
      DOB: '312.10.1980',
      Children:[
                { Name: Andrew, Age: 9 },
                { Name: Kate, Age: 4 }
               ]
    }
```

Table B:

```
{ Name: 'Mary',
      DOB: '06.06.1970',
      Children:[
                { Name: John,   Age: 6 },
                { Name: Agatha, Age: 10}
               ]
    },
    { Name: 'Bob',
      DOB: '30.03.1982',
      Children:[
                { Name: Anthony, Age: 9 },
                { Name: George,  Age: 4 },
                { Name: Frank,   Age: 2 }
               ]
    },
    { Name: 'Adam',
      DOB: '312.10.1980',
      Children:[
                { Name: Andrew, Age: 9 },
                { Name: Kate, Age: 4 },
                { Name: Jonathan,    Age: 2 }
               ]
    }
```

The output I'd like to get is:

```
Name    
----------
Bob     
Adam
```

Since the Children details are not the same for Bob or Adam in table A and table B (whenever it's the size of the record (num of children) or the details (children names etc...))

I tried to use `SELECT UNION DISTINCT` but it doesn't work on an array, I also tried `!=` and `<>` but it doesn't work on arrays...
It would be ideal to compare two arrays like you can compare two lists in Python (comparing the structure and the content).

Is there a way to implement something similar ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select name
from `project.dataset.tableA` a
join `project.dataset.tableB` b
using(name)
where a.dob != b.dob 
or (select string_agg(format('%t', s) order by name) from a.children s) 
!= (select string_agg(format('%t', s) order by name) from b.children s)
```